# What if the difference between Android LocalServerSocket and Java ServerSocket?

Tags: android, serversocket

What if the difference between Android `LocalServerSocket` and Java `ServerSocket`?
Do they have the same function?
I think LocalServerSocket is Java implementation for Linux `ServerSocket`，Java `ServerSocket` implements itself. So `LocalServerSocket` and `ServerSocket` have the same function. Am I right? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the question and I found lots of amazing stuff.

**`ServerSocket`** : waits for requests to come in over the network. It performs some operation based on that request, and then possibly returns a result to the requester. 
It uses network protocols for communications.

**`LocalServerSocket`** : Creates a new server socket **listening at specified name**. On the Android platform, **the name is created in the Linux abstract namespace (instead of on the filesystem).**

socket family is used to
       communicate between processes on the same machine efficiently.
       Traditionally, UNIX domain sockets can be either unnamed, or bound to
       a filesystem pathname (marked as being of type socket).  **Linux also
       supports an abstract namespace which is independent of the
       filesystem.**

Socket permissions have no meaning for abstract sockets: the process
       umask has no effect when binding an abstract socket, and changing
       the ownership and permissions of the object (via fchown and
       fchmod) has no effect on the accessibility of the socket. Abstract sockets automatically disappear when all open references to
       the socket are closed. The abstract socket namespace is a nonportable Linux extension.

There is differences between these two in Communications and Permissions.

More Information :
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalServerSocket
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket